# Does K8S Ingress Provide any Backend destination path along with the port?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have two web application running in same jetty.

If i simply hit the ip:port then it brings the UI application and with context path it brings another REST application.

Below are the configurations:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
      "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="war">./webapps/my-ui.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
      "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/api</Set>
    <Set name="war">./webapps/my-rest-api.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

Is there any option to provide destination path in ingress ?

Comment: you can map several routes to the same service or different services, url rewriting is possible as well, depending on what ingress controller you use of course. you may want to provide more detail on your setup and routes.

Answer (score 1):

From the Kubernetes documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) this is an ingress example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

You can add as many rules as you need to map the path to the right service and port, in your case you can have an ingress like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: ui-service
          servicePort: 80
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: rest-api-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: In that case I have to create two service and basically the port 80 you are referring different internal port. in my case two war has been depoyed in a single jetty server and for both the application the port is 80

Comment: Correct, you need two different services one per deployment and both have the internal port 80 because Kubernetes assign a different IP address on each endpoint and you don't have a conflict using the same port in both. Also, you can use the internal port directly from the war, you don't need to force the 80 port on each service if you don't want because the 80 port is on the ingress.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear how it is working, but the below code is working for me. Little confused how two context path pointing to same service and same port.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: common-service
          servicePort: 80
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: common-service
          servicePort: 80
```